# Problem with C[i] of a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, special-functions

I'm trying to solve this differential equation (depending on the `K0` parameter):

```
F[z_] := Sinh[z];
DSolve[{Q''[t] + Sinh[Q[t]] == 0, Q'[0] == 0, Q[0] == Exp[K0 I Pi]}, Q, t];
```

with no positive results...

```
DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions.
DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions.
```

Now, if I remove the initial conditions, everything works fine, and I get the double result

```
{{Q -> Function[{t}, -2 I JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[-(-2 + C[1]) (t + C[2])^2],
                                          -(4/(-2 + C[1]))]]},
 {Q -> Function[{t}, 2 I JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[-(-2 + C[1]) (t + C[2])^2],
                                         -(4/(-2 + C[1]))]]}}
```

How can I proceed in order to get the two coefficient `C[1], C[2]` determined with the two initial conditions

```
Q'[0] == 0, Q[0] == Exp[K0 I Pi]
```

I tried with `Solve` and `Reduce`:

```
Q[t_] = Q[t] /. First @ EY
Out[507]: -2 I JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[-(-2 + C[1]) (t + C[2])^2], -(4/(-2 + C[1]))]
Reduce[Q[0] == E^(I K0 Pi), C[1]]
   Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
Out[508]:Reduce[-2 I JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[-(-2 + C[1]) C[2]^2], -(4/(-2 + C[1]))] ==
                E^(I K0 Pi), C[1]]
```

but they're not working as well...
Any ideas?

Comment: What `F[z]` has to do with anything here?

Comment: Is I the sqrt(-1)?

Answer (score 3):

Once again, *Mathematica* is not very good at handling elliptic integrals and elliptic functions.

Here is the solution sought, starting from *Mathematica*'s generic solution given in the OP, and helping *Mathematica* a fair bit in inverting what it couldn't invert:

```
qfun[t_, K0_] := 2 I JacobiAmplitude[I Sinh[Exp[I K0 π]/2]
                                     (t - EllipticK[-Sinh[Exp[I K0 π]/2]^2]),
                                     -Csch[Exp[I K0 π]/2]^2]
```

This corresponds to setting `C[2] -> -EllipticK[(2 - C[1])/4]` and `C[1] -> 2 Cosh[Exp[I K0 π]]` in the generic solution.

Plot it:

```
{Plot3D[Re[qfun[t, K0]], {t, 0, 10}, {K0, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "K0", "Re(Q)"}], 
 Plot3D[Im[qfun[t, K0]], {t, 0, 10}, {K0, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "K0", "Im(Q)"}]}
 // GraphicsRow
```

[image: real and imaginary parts of solution]

Comment: Was Mathematica any help figuring that out, or did you do the inversion by hand?

Comment: The tricks were mine, but the algebra was *Mathematica*'s since I don't like writing those out by hand.

Comment: Disorder at WRI gets bigger, they haven't included `WeierstrassP` to `MathematicalFunctionData[]`, neither to `EntityList["MathematicalFunction"]`, `Entity["MathematicalFunction", "WeierstrassP"]` doesn't work either, though e.g `Entity["MathematicalFunction", "JacobiSN"]` does.  This is the state of art in version _11.1_. I don't know if in _11.2_ it is the same.

Comment: @Artes, sounds like that ought to be reported to support. On the brighter side, they finally split up the invariants and half-periods in 11.2, based on my testing of the [cloud version](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook).

Answer (score 1):

I realise this isn't really what you're asking for, but a numerical answer is as close as I've been able to get so far. I'm not convinced there is a closed-form solution for all the non-integer initial conditions `Exp[K0 I Pi]` (which might explain `DSolve`'s failure). But I'm not convinced there *isn't*, either.

You could get a numerical solution by building `K0` into `Q` explicitly. That is, make `Q = Q[t, K0]`, and using `NDSolveValue` (because, as you've discovered, `DSolve` doesn't seem to be able to do non-integer values of `K0`).

```
qfun = NDSolveValue[{D[Q[t, K0], {t, 2}] + Sinh[Q[t, K0]] == 0, 
  (D[Q[t, K0], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, Q[0, K0] == Exp[K0 I Pi]}, 
  Q, {t, 0, 10}, {K0, 0, 2}]
```

which gives you an `InterpolatingFunction` in `t` and `K0`.

Plotting the real part:

```
Plot3D[Re[qfun[t, K0]], {t, 0, 10}, {K0, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "K0", "Q"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think that is not possible to get an analytic solution, only a numerical one? Because I found the plot of the trajectories [here on Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sinh/visualizations/17/ShowAll.html) (with initial conditions the same as mine) so I guess that there should be some way... Thank you anyway for the help!

Comment: Also because the lines of the differential equation solution are slightly different from the one I found online.

Comment: I would guess the trajectories you found on Wolfram are numerical, though I couldn't swear to it. Complex initial conditions seemed to go absolutely nowhere, analytically, whichever way I tried. Initial conditions `+- 1` were no problem. I'm still not completely convinced it's impossible to build an analytic solution, but if it is possible, I think Mathematica will need a lot of help to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Another option of numerical solution is to make a module and call it for each `t` and `k`

```
f[t0_?NumericQ,k_?NumericQ]:=Module[{sol,t,Q},
   sol=Q/.First@NDSolve[{Q''[t]+Sinh[Q[t]]==0,
                    Q'[0]==0,Q[0]==Exp[k I Pi]},Q,{t,t0,t0+.1}];
   sol[t0]
];

Plot3D[Re[Evaluate[f[t, k]]], {t, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 2}, 
                AxesLabel -> {"t", "K0", "Q"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried series solution by Maple, but for some reason, the solution it gives does not match the above, no time to find out why. But here it is any way:

```
restart;
Order:=6:
sol:=dsolve({diff(q(t),t$2) + sinh(q(t)) = 0, 
       D(q)(0)=0, q(0) = exp(k*I*Pi)}, q(t),'series'):

sol:=convert(sol,polynom):
f:=unapply(rhs(sol),t,k);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
plot3d(Re(f(t,k)),t=0..10,k=0..2);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think Mathematica's solution is wrong... perhaps Maple provides the right one, but I cannot say why...